# node_modules not requiring xjs-framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am trying to make a simple xsplit overlay, I have followed the quick setup guide but installed "xjs-framework" using npm install xjs-framework and I am trying to require it but it seems like its not working even when I point directly to it as suggested by the advanced guide:

> The relevant file is node_modules/xjs-framework/dist/xjs.js

```
var xjs = require('C:/Users/Ben Wall/Desktop/Xsplit_fortnite_CURRENT/node_modules/xjs-framework/dist/xjs.js');
```

EDIT: this is what i have in my index.html

```
    <html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stream-status">
    Wins:
  </div>
  <script src="node_modules/request"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/xjs-framework/dist/xjs.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

and this is what i have in main.js

```
var xjs             = require('xjs');
var request         = require('request');

xjs.ready().then(function() {
  xjs.ChannelManager.on('stream-start', function() {
    document.getElementById('stream-status').innerHTML = "Wins ${getwinsFunction}";



  });

  xjs.ChannelManager.on('stream-end', function() {
    document.getElementById('stream-status').innerHTML = 'Wins: ';
  });
})
```

sorry for format 
anyway i can sucsessfully require xjs but i cannot require request using the same method??

EDIT: i need the request module because im adding more code once i can figure this out

```
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);

    const wins = info.lifeTimeStats[8].key + ": " + info.lifeTimeStats[8].value;
```

Comment: copy off everything before `xjs-framework`

Comment: i have tried that just now but nothing, sucks i cant see the errors

Comment: or just try `xjs` or `xjs-framework`

Comment: i can require xjs now but i also need to require the request package

Comment: most node modules you won't have to.

Comment: you can't mix that in the browser natively without something like browserify or webpack.

Comment: ah ok i get it now thanks i will try that now